# Ansible: Exclude a parameter if variable is not set

Tags: ansible

Is there a way to exclude a parameter entirely if a variable is *not* set?  I do not want to use a default value for this, I simply do not way the parameter referenced at all.

For example,

```
---
- name: manage_aix_lvm | creating new VG
  # https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/aix_lvg_module.html#aix-lvg-module
  aix_lvg:
    force: "{{ item.force | default('no') }}"
    pp_size: "{{ item.ppsize }}"
    pvs: "{{ item.disks | join(',') }}"
    vg: "{{ item.vgname }}"
    state: present
  become: true
  loop: "{{ lvm_groups }}"
```

In the event that variable item.ppsize is *not* set I want to exclude that entire parameter from being included.  The reason for this is that this is an optional parameter, and if not set, the Operating System will automatically calculate the value.

Is this possible within a single task?  Or will I need to create multiple Tasks/Resources to check if item.ppsize is set and redirect to different tasks/resources?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Q: ***"If the variable item.ppsize is not set exclude that parameter."***

A: Set the default value to the special variable [*omit*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#making-variables-optional)

```yaml
    pp_size: "{{ item.ppsize|default(omit) }}"
```